# On testing compatibility of a new OS with laptop/computer using Live CD

Tags: boot, cd

Is testing compatibility of a (new/different) OS with one's computer best done using a Live CD? So, if after booting up from a Live CD, things check out as 'OK', is it fair to assume that a full install of that OS will result in the same?

**Are there any gotchas here?** (wireless, sound card, camera etc. etc.)

In my specific case, I want to test if I can install FreeBSD on a Dell Precision laptop. I am hoping to test that using the FreeBSD Live CD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Live USB is easier yet, in my opinion. Some PC's don't have CD/DVD drives, but most *do* have USB ports. Flash drives tend to be faster than CD's, too, in my experience. And yes, either method gives a chance to use the OS without installing anything... unless you decide to do so, after testing.

Comment: I see how a Live USB would make it easier and faster. And now having brought that up, since (unlike a CD) USB can be written into as well, is it possible to set it up such that packages can be installed and tested even though it is a Live USB boot?

Comment: Just learned this about the FreeBSD Live CD at https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/using-live-cd.html that "This option only provides a command prompt and not a graphical interface." As a result, now, I really do need to install a GUI package since I want to evaluate if I can use FreeBSD as a desktop OS on the laptop. So, the need to install packages in a Live USB boot/session has only increased!

Comment: Ubuntu Live DVD/USB *does* have a GUI... in fact, it looks just as if it's running from the HDD. Sorry that FreeBSD does not. Look into a Live distro with *persistence*, which allows you to write to a USB as if it were on the HDD, so you could do a full install *on the USB*. Not sure if FreeBSD has that, but see https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ for a Ubuntu tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

A "Live CD" (i.e. may be any MEDIA, as long at it is bootable) will most probably contain drivers for common hardware.
Generally I'd say; if your all your hardware runs with <distribution>-Live, then you most likely will be able to at least INSTALL that particular driver.

Note: It might be necessary to look up the driver, and actively install it.

It may also be so that there is a "open source" driver of good quality, and it is used on the live-disk; a faster(?) more option rich closed source variant may also be available; e.g. noveau and nvidia drivers.